# How to customize nvd3's tooltips and remove labels from x axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I have this chart, but as you can see it has some problems:
[image]

1. The tooltip height is wrong, there is that ugly blank space at the top. Since nvd3 has no documentation I really don't know how to proceed;
2. The x axis labels are all overlapping, I want either to remove them or to tilt them (like 45 deg.). The second option is best. I also tried `.staggeredLabels(true)` but they still overlap.

EDIT: I solved the second one by removing labels. Actually I don't remove them but rather hide them with:

```
.nv-x text {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no one answered I just post the solution to the second problem:

```
.nv-x text {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The blank spot is actually the key. It seems like maybe your object doesn't have a name?

Comment: Thank you for being interested in this! However I don't have access anymore to that code, so I cannot even try... :(